# Java Arraylist size after nested for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 arraylist, the first one is contain 300 area population and the other one contain the adoption rate of that 300 area.
I would like to calculate each area's new population. However, after doing a nested for loop calculation. The size of the arraylist had change it to 90000. Why it happen? What I did wrong?

```
private void calArray(){
    int k;
    double n,v;
    int result;
    int popSize = populArrayList.size();
    int adoptSize = adoptArrayList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < popSize; i++){

        k = populArrayList.get(i);

        for(int j = 0; j < adoptSize; j++){


            n = adoptArrayList.get(j);

            v = k + (k * n);

            pv1.add(Math.floor(v));
            System.out.println(pv1.size());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a loop inside a loop and you keep adding to a collection inside it, and now you're wondering why the list gets bigger?

Comment: sorry i m new to java. If i m not doing that how could I calculate the result? Just make it in 2 loop?

Comment: @kings077712 what is you want to achieve?

Comment: It's not a java issue. It's a "what are you doing?" issue. Read my comment again - the code is doing exactly what you told it to...

Comment: I have 2 arraylist the first one is the population and the second one is the population's adoption rate. I want to calculate the new population. Both of them are contain 300 value. it should be arraylist1 index[1] * arraylist2 index[1].

Comment: are you sure that the size of two list will be always equal?

Comment: yea it is always equal i read it from file! @Jobin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the size of two lists are same. You can replace the for loops with a single for loop as follows.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < populArrayList.size(); i++) {

        k = populArrayList.get(i);
        n = adoptArrayList.get(i);

        v = k + (k * n);

        pv1.add(Math.floor(v));

    }
```